# jqGrid serializeDelData working but serializeEditData not

Tags: jqgrid

this delete working but edit doesn't where I am wrong?

```
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.del, {
        serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
            console.log("test");
            return postdata;
        }
    });

    jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
        serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
            console.log("edit");
            return postdata;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that you use [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) and not for example inline editing ([inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) for example and other)?

Comment: yes, you were right!serializeRowData fixed my problem! you can convert this to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you inline editing ([inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) for example and other) instead of [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing)? `serializeEditData` works only with the form editing.

Comment: Thx Oleg, as usually.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass extra data with inline editing using serializeRowData event of grid.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow

```
serializeRowData: function (postData) {
return $.extend(true, {}, postData, {
    account: jQuery('input[name=account]').val(),
    code: jQuery('input[name=code]').val()
});
```